# Notice (8): unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 743 bytes in Cakephp for JSON Array serialize

Tags: php, cakephp, json

I am getting error:Notice (8): unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 743 bytes when i try to display JSON encoded array in page.

I am iterating all users in a foreach loop to get user details as array format. The array format looks like below:

```
$userDetails =
    Array
    (
        [id] => 12121212
        [enc_userid] => QWQWQWQWdssd
        [img_path] => http://192.168.1.XX/pjt/images/getuserphoto/SDSDSDSDSD/1/big/
        [msg_icon] => http://192.168.1.XX/pjt/img/sd/4a-icons/msg.png
        [rdd_icon] => http://192.168.1.XX/pjt/img/sd/4a-icons/invite.png
        [profile_path] => http://192.168.1.XX/pjt/user/sd/HJHJHJH
        [name] => XXX XXXXXXXXX
        [type] => IND
        [photo] => XXXXX.jpg
        [designation] => XXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [company] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX Pvt Ltd
        [insid] => 
        [status] => 1
        [city] => XDXX, XXX,XXX
        [xxxx_id] => XXXX
    )
```

Then this array is serialized and displayed like:

```
echo serialize($userDetails);
```

The foreach loop looks like this:

```
$ui_array = array();
    foreach ($search_data as $key => $val) {
        $ui_array[] = unserialize($this->function_to_fetch_user_details($user_id));
    }
echo json_encode($ui_array);exit;
```

But i am getting a false at beginning for JSON array like:

```
[false,{"id":"11168","enc_userid":"dsdsdsd","img_path":"http:\/\/192.168.1.dd\/sdsdsd\/images\/getuserphoto\/sdsdsd\/1\/big\/","msg_icon":"http:\/\/192.168.1.sd\/sdsd\/img\/sdheme\/icons\/msg.png" ...................
```

with error Notice (8): unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 743 bytes.

I am not understanding why this error is happening now as it was working perfect previously.
Any help will be very helpful, Thank you!

Comment: The question is what happened between the serialization and unserialization.

Comment: The question is absolutely clear i have given the exact array format before serialization and the json response after un-serialization :):):)

Comment: @GeorgeJoffinJoy: You getting **false** because your first call to `unserialize($this->function_to_fetch_user_details($user_id))` returning false. I am wondering, are you calling the function with same `$user_id`?

Comment: @xiidea No all user ids are unique ids.... wonder whats missing???

Comment: @GeorgeJoffinJoy: Throughout the loop there is no sign of changing it!

Comment: @xiidea in fact all records are fetched using same function which returns same array format and only the first record seems to return false...

Answer (score 0):

Probable reason you are getting the false may be the same reason you are getting the error:

Let we debug:

Modify your code to be something like:

```
$ui_array = array();
    foreach ($search_data as $key => $val) {
        serializedData = $this->function_to_fetch_user_details($user_id);
         $array = unserialize(serializedData);
         if($array == false) {
           die("error Found with : " . serializedData;
         }
         $ui_array[] = unserialize($this->function_to_fetch_user_details($user_id));
    }
echo json_encode($ui_array);exit;
```